# '._drawable is not a directory' error in Android Studio hedgehog

Tags: android, image, kotlin

I am working on the Android Studio with my MacBook and Found this error inside my program.

'/Volumes/HOMEWORK/DiceRollerSolution/app/build/intermediates/packaged_res/debug/._drawable' is not a directory

I dont know why does that happen, as I keep thinking it does a hidden files and keep press Command+Shift+>(the period) to try to reveal the hidden file, but that doesn't work, and still, not solve the issue. Now I run out the idea and don't know how to solve it. I really just need to get this to run.

I know it look like a simple issue but I can't for the life of me to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

This type of files are automatically created by MacOS on volumes other than Apple native or Unix/UFS ones. I had to erase my removable disk to an APFS file system to make Android Studio work properly on that disk. Do not forget to back up your important files before erasing that disk.